# Getting a variable from a Entry into a dbf

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to use a entry to append the dbf part of a shapefile. So far I can only make a change to the dbf file by directly assigning the variable a value. I can only get the entry box to print a variable. What am I missing? I am using python 3.3.

```
import shapefile
from tkinter import filedialog 
import tkinter as tk
class application:
    def __init__(self,window):
        """ Initalize the Application """
        self.myentrybox = tk.Entry(window)
        self.myentrybox.pack()
        self.myentrybox.insert(0,"some default value")
        self.myentrybox.bind("<Return>",self.Enter)

    def Enter(self,event):
       """ Someone Pressed Enter """
       print  (self.myentrybox.get())
aep = 'self.myentrybox.get()'
root=tk.Tk()
myapp = application(root)
r = shapefile.Reader('Mississippi')
w = shapefile.Writer()
w.fields = list(r.fields)
w.field (aep, 'C', '40')
i=1

for rec in r.records():
 rec.append(i)
 i+=1
 w.records.append(rec)
w._shapes.extend(r.shapes())
w.save('AMissl6KM')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are saving the shapefile before the GUI appears on the screen. Is that intentional?

Comment: Its not, I am to new at this to understand how to get the parts to work in the correct order.